# Is there any way to monitor an upload, byte by byte, in Flash or AIR?

Tags: flash, file-upload, air, progress

I'm uploading files to the server in Flash and am flustered by how there doesn't appear to be any mechanism by which I can monitor the upload progress.  It gives me a callback for when it's finished, but unlike the download mechanism which has callbacks for every time the buffer has changed size, the upload appears to just be a black box.

Is there any way I can extend any underlying class to write my own uploader that would be notified as the files goes up?

any and all advice on this would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Have you tried ProgressEvent?

Comment: Doesn't ProgressEvent.PROGRESS get triggered during uploads? It's supposed to: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf8.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ce9

Comment: ProgressEvent fires as you read bytes from the file while it's still local... it doesn't report back as the transfer goes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use progress event

example : http://www.flashwonderland.com/flash-actionscript-upload-file/as3-uploading-files-05.html